# На утро / наутро

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Встреча была перенасена на утро / наутро.

> На утро / наутро я запланировал поесть гречонку.

> Наутро / на утро я съел четверть кг гречонки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Встреча была перенесена на (что?) утро.***

***На (что?) утро я запланировал почесть гречонку.***

***Наутро (= утром) я съел четверть кг гречонки.***

[«Грамота ру»](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE&all=x):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другие варианты:

***Встреча была перенесена наутро (= утром)***;

***Наутро (= утром) я запланировал поесть гречонку***.