# «Наутро» или «на утро»?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно, наречия, существительные

Как правильно писать **на утро / наутро** в следующем предложении?
*Лекция была записана **на утро** после чемпионата.*

Comment: если записана когда? - то наутро(наречие). А если записана на что/на когда/ на какое время?(появляется предлог) тогда на_утро.

Comment: У нас "наутро" идет на рекорд: 5 тем на форуме, из них два вопроса задал Леопольд.  Что за загадочное слово!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [На утро / наутро](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476094/%d0%9d%d0%b0-%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be)

Answer (score 1):

• В этом предложении правильно писать слитно (= утром):
*Лекция была записана **наутро** после чемпионата.*

Из справочника: [**нау́тро**](https://oross.ruslang.ru/article/link/nautro1) (правописание наречий и наречных сочетаний):

> пишется слитно как исключение из правила о раздельном написании наречных сочетаний, включающих существительное, употребляемое в разных предложно-падежных формах.

Здесь подразумевается первое или второе значение глагола [*записать*](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=42):
**1.** *что.* Изложить что-либо в письменном виде; занести на бумагу. З*аписать доклад.*
**2.** *кого-что.* Нанести на пластинку, плёнку, кассету с помощью специального записывающего устройства (голос, музыку, изображение). *Записать концерт.*

•• Если же подразумевается третье значение (внести в список, в расписание; ***кого***), то лучше использовать другой глагол. Тогда пишем раздельно:
*Лекция была **назначена на утро** после чемпионата.*

**На утро** в этом случае — это сочетание предлога **на** с существительным **утро**.
Для проверки можно задать вопрос "что?": *Лекция была назначена на* (что? на какое время?) *утро*.
Или встроить определение: *Лекция была назначена **на раннее утро**.*

Answer (score 0):

Все просто: *Лекция была записана **наутро** после чемпионата.*

Нет падежного управления для предлога ***НА***, лекцию нельзя записать **(на что?) на утро.** Но можно записать **утром** следующего после чемпионата дня.

**НАУТРО**

**Русский орфографический словарь:** наутро, нареч. (утром следующего дня: наутро выступили в поход), но сущ. на утро (отложить разговор на утро)